# Is there a faster option than this foreach loop in a vba macro?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, each

I am trying to create a macro to format my stock sheets. I need to only show values up to 8 and then show 9+ for any value over that. I also need to get rid of any 0's or negative numbers.

I need to run this loop 4 times on columns C, D, E and F and the file is about 15,000 lines long. The code works when I debug it, but it crashes the application if it just runs through. I know I can't loop through that much, but is there another way that I can do it?

```
Call SetStockLevels(range("C3:C" & lastRow))

Private Sub SetStockLevels(range As range)

    For Each c In range
        If c.Value < 1 Then
            c.ClearContents
        ElseIf c.Value > 8 Then
            c.Value = "9+"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I already have these funtions that I call at the start and the end of the macro respectively.

```
Public Sub speedup()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

End Sub

Public Sub normal()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: 15000 lines isn't very much - that shouldn't make it crash.  Maybe you can keep it from crashing by putting a DoEvents in the loop?

Comment: Maybe store the value in an array, process the array then paste the entire value back into the range?

Comment: You may want to use Select Case instead of If Then

Comment: I wonder if "in range" pre-allocates something when compiled. . . can you log a message every record and see when it crashes perhaps ? Maybe it has something to do with the actual value rather than number of records..

Comment: Does it actually 'crash', or is it just slow (and is unresponsive while running)? This runs in about 1 second on my old machine. But perhaps you have formulae and formatting in yours which would slow it down?

Comment: There are other things it is doing like deleting columns, changing colours etc. I just ran one instance of SetStockLevels() and it took 49 seconds. Maybe my computer is just ridiculously slow. The application becomes unresponsive, but maybe if I left it alone for 4-5 minutes then it would be ok.

Comment: See the answer below. It made the update almost instantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method stores the range value in an array and process from it which should be much faster than looping through cell by cell.

If your starting and ending row in column C-F are the same, you can pass the entire range and process it together.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheet1.Range("C" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    SetStockLevels Sheet1.Range("C3:F" & lastRow)
End Sub

Private Sub SetStockLevels(setRng As Range)

    Dim tempArr As Variant
    
    tempArr = setRng.Value
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    For j = LBound(tempArr, 2) To UBound(tempArr, 2)
        For i = LBound(tempArr, 1) To UBound(tempArr, 1)
            Select Case tempArr(i, j)
                Case Is < 1: tempArr(i, j) = ""
                Case Is > 8: tempArr(i, j) = "9+"
            End Select
        Next i
    Next j
    
    setRng.Value = tempArr
End Sub
```

Comment: You beat me by one minute! Nice answer.

Comment: @PGSystemTester Haha I just saw your answer and was like "It's like a mirror".

Comment: I know... same dang variables and everything! You should change from "much faster" to "unbelievably faster"!

Comment: That worked great. Dropped the time it took to complete from 10+ minutes to about a second! For some reason it didn’t work if I passed the whole Range(“C3:C” & lastRow) to it. It only worked on column C, but did nothing on columns D to F. I just called it for each column and it was fine. Thanks heaps.

Comment: @Schming is that a typo? Shouldnt you pass `Range("C3:F" & lastRow)`?

Comment: Yes that is a typo in the comment.

Comment: @Schming I made an edit to the code previously, check that its `Select Case tempArr(i,j)`

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with **Regular Expressions**

I thought regexp replacements would work faster, but it takes almost similar time...

```
Sub SetStockLevels()
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer
'________________Timer Start_______________
Dim myrng As Range, mystr As String, arr, col As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

Dim regex As Object, mc As Object
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.regexp")
regex.ignorecase = False
regex.Global = True

lastRow = Sheet1.Range("C" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set myrng = Sheet1.Range("C3:F" & lastRow)

For Each col In myrng.Columns
    mystr = "," & Join(Application.Transpose( _
        Application.Index(col.Value, 0, 1)), ",") & ","
    
    regex.Pattern = "-\d*(\.?\d*)" 'for negative numbers including decimal
    mystr = regex.Replace(mystr, "")
    regex.Pattern = ",0," 'for zeros
    mystr = regex.Replace(mystr, ",,")
'__________________________________________________________________
    'for numbers with decimals skip below two regex replacements _
    'and use the loop below. Not sure how to get regex match for decimals > 8
    regex.Pattern = "[0-9]{2,}" 'for numbers greater than 9
    mystr = regex.Replace(mystr, "9+")
    regex.Pattern = ",9," 'for Nine (Single digit)
    mystr = regex.Replace(mystr, ",9+,")
'__________________________________________________________________

    arr = Split(Mid(mystr, 2, Len(mystr) - 2), ",")
    
'    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
'        If arr(i) <> "" And arr(i) > 8 Then arr(i) = "9+"
'    Next i
    
    col.Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
Next col

'________________Timer End_______________
'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
'Notify user in seconds
  Debug.Print "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```